# QT QSvgRenderer rotated text disappears

Tags: c++, qt, svg, fonts

When I render an SVG with QSvgRenderer it shows text properly on my local machine. On the server if text is rotated it simply disappears. I tried instally freetype2 and pango and recompiling but it doesn't fix the situation.

What am I missing?

NOTE: Both my local deployment and my remote server run with xvfb-run.

Comment: `QSvgRenderer` is not using X library calls, so that won't be a problem. All modern Qt apps use the raster rendering backend on all platforms, by default. Please tell us exactly what version of Qt, on what distribution, etc.

Comment: I am using Debian 7.8 with Qt 5.3.2 from wheezy-backports. Anyway, in my laptop I tried running it without QGuiApplication but I got a segmentation fault when adding text to the SVG. Once I initialized the QGuiApplication it required X.

Comment: From QT 5.4 documentation: "Warning: Qt requires that a QGuiApplication object exists before any paint devices can be created. Paint devices access window system resources, and these resources are not initialized before an application object is created.".So, Xvfb seems required.

Comment: The "window system" is really a bad way of referring to the platform plugin. You can use a dummy plugin that doesn't require X at all! It's your choice what platform plugin you use.

Comment: Can you give a link to an example or to the documentation on how to achieve font rendering in Qt using a dummy plugin?

Comment: The plugin is only a means of interfacing Qt with some sort of screen I/O etc. Font rendering is a separate issue IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with text rendering, the problem was that text was being translated outside of the viewport. The cause is that there is a bug in Qt SVG module. It does no treat the rotation transformation properly. I opened a bug report on Qt bugtracker:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46883